# How can I fix my dependencies installing vim

Tags: installing

I had vim working for a while and uninstalled it for no good reason. To reinstall it I gave the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get warnings that the respository `deadsnakes/ppa` and `pycharm/ubuntu` are not secure, but nothing that seems relevant (I guess)

```
sudo apt-get upgrade vim-runtime
sudo apt-get upgrade vim-common
sudo -i apt-get install vim

vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.1.0320-1ubuntu3.1) but 2:8.1.0875-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
      Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:8.1.0320-1ubuntu3.1) but 2:8.1.0875-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

I then tried

```
apt-get install -f
```

This appears to have done nothing since it says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded`.

So I am pretty much stumped.

After getting vim working again, I would like to enable the system clipboard. I read that this is accomplished by installing `vim-gnome`. When I tried to do that, I encountered similar issues.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've [edit]ed your question to make better use of our markdown syntax. On an unrelated note, I wonder if [unix.se] might not be able to help more? It seems like an ubuntu version issue.

Comment: You might also want to consider [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), you'll find a lot more experts on Ubuntu package management there...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with

```
sudo aptitude install vim
```

When aptitude told me about the dependencies and offered to fix them, I had tried saying yes, but that did not help. However, saying `n` caused aptitude to offer to downgrade the packages to their correct versions. When I said `Y` to that, it successfully installed vim.

Then it was easy to install vim-gnome with the command

```
sudo aptitude install vim-gnome
```

This, combined with the settings

```
Plugin 'repeat.vim'
Plugin 'vim-easyclip.vim'
```

in my vimrc allowed the paste operations to use the system clipboard, which was the ultimate goal. At least this last step is specific to vim and may be helpful to others.

A happy ending if the downgrading of the vim common and runtime does not have side effects!

Comment: You may learn to use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make your post more readable.